# How to determine the exact type of GCP load balancer that is being used?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have a nginx instance in GKE with a default service with `type: LoadBalancer`. How can I view the exact type of load balancer it is in comparison to this GCP LB doc below? And if this is a Proxy or Passthrough?

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary-of-google-cloud-load-balancers

Edit: Exampple.. How do i determine between these two?

TCP Proxy or External network TCP/UDP? TCP Proxy is a proxy and the latter is the passthrough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GKE, according with the YAML file definition (and annotations) you can create [3 types of load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#background)

- Internal TCP/UDP load balancer (passthrough)
- External TCP/UDP load balancer (passthrough)
- External HTTP global load balancer (HTTP/HTTPS only)

So, not TCP proxy load balancer.

Check the type of load balancer in the UI if you want.

Comment: Thank you. Someone had mentioned to me it was possible to have a L4 TCP Proxy LB for GKE so i was very confused.

Answer (score 1):

As per this moment, GKE is not compatible with [TCP Proxy LB](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#outside-cluster), when you use `type: LoadBalancer` GCP will provide a [Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#ext-lb) which is a regional resource that delivers traffic via [pass-through](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#summary-of-google-cloud-load-balancers).

You can see all your load balancers on [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/loadBalancers/list) to determine what type they are once created.